# Joining two aggregation results in mongodb using $out of aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a reporting app, and I generate mongodb commands, and it involves running three aggregate calls. The aggregate calls have [match,group,project] in their pipes.

```
RESULT OF AGGREGATE 1-3
{_id: <XXX>, ...}
```

The grouping "_id" for these calls are same, but, because their $match are different they cannot be in the same aggregate call. I need to join all of these aggregation results. I know that one way to solve this is using conditions during the $group stage, but the problem is the conditions are really complicated to mix with the already complex $group pipe.

To give some context why that solution is very difficult if not impossible; the data is quite huge, each doc has 700 attributes, and the docs are coming it at around 1k per day. Generating such complicated condition into EACH field in the $group stage will make a mess.

I have seen answers that are running map-reduce to combine these aggregation results, but I am looking for other solutions. As I've researched, aggregate has an $out pipe. Is there any way that I can manipulate that $out pipe to join these aggregation results? (The reason for thinking of $out is that I have to save ALL the results anyway as a report)

Comment: Okay so `$out` always overwrites a collection, and what you are basically going to need to do is iterate cursors and either output to another collection per cursor iteration or do whatever you need to do. And it's that detail that is completely missing from the question. Forget the big scary numbers as they are not relevant. Instead describe the actual problem with basic document examples and a desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want to go ahead with merging the aggregation results, then you can create an output collection using bulk upserts. For performance you can create a compound index on this output collection, which has your grouping attributes.

```
dataArray.map(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(err, row){
        var setOnInsert = {grouping_attrs: row.grouping_values, v1: row.v1}
        var set = {v2: row.v2}
        var query = {grouping_attrs: row.grouping_values}
        bulk.find(query).upsert().update({$setOnInsert: setOnInsertStmt, $set: set});
    })    
})
```

Here your `dataArray` is created using find on the `$out` collections.

Comment: Basically on the right approach, but it needs context. People just don't use the mongodb shell to deploy applications. There are language specific and other parts of the question that would have been better clarified. So this is actually "too broad" an aswer in that it cannot address all the issues that are not explained in the question.

Comment: Was trying to give hint into how to do it.Sure will take into consideration your feedback while answering. Thanks for it.

Comment: I "agree" that it's probably the right approach. But the OP's question is way to broad for a certain assertion.